# Performance Timing in Internet Explorer 11 - requestStart always equal to responseStart

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, web, timing

I'm trying to compute the duration that the server took to process requests (requestStart - responseStart) and I'm using the [Performance Timing API](http://www.w3.org/blog/2012/09/performance-timing-information/).

Chrome (37) and Firefox (32) both give similar results (35-40ms difference), but IE 11 always returns equal values for *requestStart* and *responseStart*, so that server time is always 0.

Is this a known issue or am I using the wrong properties for calculating the durations?
I'm using the same algorithm as [Glimpse](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/glimpse.js#L3624).

```
networkPre = getDiff(timings, 'navigationStart', 'requestStart'),
networkPost = getDiff(timings, 'responseStart', 'responseEnd'),
network = networkPre + networkPost,
server = getDiff(timings, 'requestStart', 'responseStart'), //<----- this is always 0 in IE, 35-40ms in Chrome & FF
browser = getDiff(timings, 'responseEnd', 'loadEventEnd'),
total = network + server + browser;
```